# Changing formset's form initial values Django Class Based Views

Tags: django, django-forms

Good morning people. The problem is that I want to change a field value by another form value given a condition. I'm using django-extra-views package to display a formset:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(MyView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    formset = context['formset']
    if self.object.bool_field: 
        for frm in formset:
            frm.fields['another_field'].initial = frm.instance.value
    context['formset'] = formset
    return context
```

The condition is fine, I logged some info and worked fine. But when the form is rendered, the value for another_field field is not the correct. I'm guessing that the formset is not mutable (no errors given), I'm missing something here?

Thanks in advance